# Add multiple names to html input?

Tags: html

Perhaps I am misunderstanding the use of names in inputs.

I want to add: `_charset_` to the following input:

```
<input name="test" />
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why, what is your end goal?

Comment: The server is decoding the inputs incorrectly

Comment: Charset should be defined using metadata in the document - it has nothing to do with the name attribute of an `input` element.

Comment: create another input with name `_charset_` and set its `type` to `hidden`

Comment: Another possibility is that the charset of your server is set incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone- really appreciate it. @agtabesh, could you elaborate how that would work?

Comment: If you want to send data you can use `<input name="_charset_" type="hidden" />`. `type="hidden"` makes `input` to be hidden from user. Of course, if you want to set charset you need just to add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to `head` tag.